# Как взять цвет из списка, чтобы присвоить значению в цикле?

Tags: python, циклы, цвета

Нужно сгенерировать круги в цикле и каждому присвоить свой цвет, взятый из кортежа, используя функцию enumerate. Собственно не могу понять как сделать, благодарю за любые ответы

```
import tkinter
import time
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
canvas.pack()

colors = ('blue3', 'brown', 'black','blue violet','blue4','chartreuse','coral1')
r = random.randint(0, 400)# случайные значения для координаты центра окружности
x = r# переменная центра окружности
y = r# переменная центра окружности

for R in range(150,181,5):
    list_ = list(enumerate(colors))
    
    canvas.create_oval(x - R, y - R, x + R, y + R, outline=  )
    canvas.update()# обновление - запуск нового круга
    time.sleep(0.05) # пауза перед новым кругом
   
    
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не в том месте используете enumerate

```
import tkinter
import time
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
canvas.pack()

colors = ('blue3', 'brown', 'black','blue violet','blue4','chartreuse','coral1')
r = random.randint(0, 400)# случайные значения для координаты центра окружности
x = r# переменная центра окружности
y = r# переменная центра окружности

for color, R in enumerate(range(150,181,5)):
    canvas.create_oval(x - R, y - R, x + R, y + R, outline=colors[color]  )
    canvas.update()# обновление - запуск нового круга
    time.sleep(0.05) # пауза перед новым кругом
   
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не смогу, бот ответ в тесте не пропустит.
"Потом в программе должен начаться бесконечный цикл, в каждой итерации которого должна быть анимация появления семи концентрических кругов с цветами из кортежа colors и радиусами 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175 и 180 пикселей. Для того чтобы сгенерировать последовательность из радиусов, используйте функцию range с шагом 5. Убедитесь, что последний радиус именно 180. Для получения индекса цвета, который будет совпадать с индексом радиуса, используйте функцию enumerate."

Comment: ну так и нужно было написать в вопросе. мы же не можем мысли читать. я исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понятно, как вписать это в цикл, чтобы каждый круг имел один из семи цветов, указанных в переменной

Comment: я вам уже нарисовал цикл. в нем каждый круг бедет иметь свой радиус R и свой цвет colors[color]. вставьте в этот цикл отрисовку с указанными параметрами, и все.

Comment: Я наверное, совсем не пойму, у меня сам код  в вопросе.  Там в Tkinter, при помощи цикла рисуются круги, именно графически рисуются, а не возвращаются функцией Print. Вот их нужно раскрасить.

Comment: да, вы явно не понимаете своего кода. вместо своего цикла используйте мой.

Comment: я обновил ответ, но не могу проверить его работу, потому что не пользуюсь tkinter. а вам нужно уже начинать понимать, что вы пишите.

Comment: Все верно, ведь я только учусь)  Благодарю именно это и было нужно